# Proper way to create a IDXGIFactory7

Tags: visual-studio-2019, dxgi

I am working on a DirectX 11 app and I am having difficulties creating an instance of IDXGIFactory7. I could not find a CreateDXGIFactory7() function so I am using CreateDXGIFactory2() like this:

```
IDXGIFactory7* factory;
HRESULT hr = ::CreateDXGIFactory2(DXGI_CREATE_FACTORY_DEBUG, __uuidof(IDXGIFactory7), (void**)&factory);
```

The difficulty I am having is that this call throws an exception when attempting to use the graphics debugger in Visual Studio 2019.  I also tried IDXGIFactory6 which also throws an exception.  If I change it to IDXGIFactory2 it works and I can use the graphics debugger.

This code does run and debug fine using the regular debugger, but not the graphics debugger.  I get the following exception:

```
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFAE1513B29 in DirectXTemplated.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: GRFXTool::ToolException at memory location 0x0000004D28BFE010.
```

I downloaded the sample from https://www.3dgep.com/introduction-to-directx-11/ and modified it to use IDXGIFactory7 and CreateDXGIFactory2() instead of IDXGIFactory in the QueryRefreshRate() function. You will need to set ***g_EnableVSync = TRUE*** at the top of main.cpp for it to create the factory. This does generate the exception when attempting to use the graphics debugger.

This is a Windows 10 Pro x64 installation with Visual Studio v16.7.6.

Comment: Which Windows 10 build are you using?

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn Windows 10 version 1909,OS version 18363.1198.

Comment: You should file this is as a bug with [Report a Problem...](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/).

Comment: "throws an exception" is insufficient description. What happens next? Is the exception handled or passed outside of API call? If handled, what is the `hr`? Are things differrent when you don't pass `DXGI_CREATE_FACTORY_DEBUG`? Finally, one another easy workaround you need to try on the questionale system is to request `IDXGIFactory` and after receiving an interface pointer `QueryInterface` for `IDXGIFactory7`.

Comment: @RomanR. The exception is not handled and the debugger will not let you continue.  No hr is returned, so you can't check it.  Removing DXGI_CREATE_FACTORY_DEBUG did not change anything.  Your last suggestion, though, did work and I will post a solution based on that.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comment from Roman R., the way to get around the problem seems to be to use CreateDXGIFactory2() to create an IDXGIFactory2 and use QueryInterface() on that to obtain the one for IDXGIFactory7.

Doing it this way avoids the exception and the app runs under the graphics debugger without issue.

Comment: it's not really a proper solution, true it bypass this bug but casting the interface this way causes other bugs when using this interface later on "ESP was not properly saved across a function call when using function pointers"

Comment: @ma1169 There is a much better work around, actually. Put a short-cut to Visual Studio 2019 on your desktop. Right-click it and from the context menu choose "Run with graphics processor" and then choose your high performance option. Everything will enumerate properly and my original method for creating the factory mentioned above will work. That menu option is not available from the start menu or pinning VS to the task bar, only from a short-cut.