# How to debug shaders using PIX

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, shader, directx-12

Simply I want to debug shaders, I tried Visual studio 2019 & 2022's graphic debuggers but they don't work and I tried the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64903828/proper-way-to-create-a-idxgifactory7) but it doesnt work either. DirectX12 is not supported by Visual Studio Graphic Debuggers

Thus I looked for an alternative and I found Pix, but I am struggling with the basics for instance, I can't use the watch menu to check the value of constants, it shows them as unavailable most of the time, I have to use constant menu to do so(but at-least this works).

The biggest Issue is this, When I step over/in lines, it does skip a single line or multiple lines and when I set a break point at any of these lines, it shows this message "No code exists at this location"

[image: No Code Exist at this location]

I cant tell whether these lines get processed or not from the debugger, and Most importantly I want to know the values they hold. Any Idea how to force pix to calculate every line?

Comment: Are you running release or debug version of your application? How do you compile your shaders, at runtime or maybe using offline shader compiler?

Comment: I run the debug version,  and shader is compiled  at runtime

Comment: What do you use for runtime shader compilation? Is it DirectXShaderCompiler?

Comment: yes, D3DCompileFromFile

Comment: Ok, that's not DXC but doesn't matter. Do you pass any shader flags into your D3DCompile FromFile call?

Comment: D3DCOMPILE_ENABLE_STRICTNESS D3DCOMPILE_DEBUG D3DCOMPILE_SKIP_OPTIMIZATION

Comment: Hmm I thought you maybe didn't used D3DCOMPILE_SKIP_OPTIMIZATION. Do you use Visual Studio? Can you compile your shader with their builtin HLSL compiler using atleast SM 6.0 ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234358/discussion-between-ma1169-and-zezanjee).